# question closed due to opinion

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons, reopen-closed

I posed a question which was closed as it was deemed that answers would be mostly opinion based.  I think it is true that I will get mostly opinions, but I really want to hear what people have to say.  If they can make a good case for their opinion I might well adopt it.  I am really unsure how to proceed and would like to hear what others think.

I can't think of a way to rewrite the question that would avoid this problem.  Any suggestions about what to do next, other than continue to fumble along with my situation?

Comment: Opinion-based questions are off-topic. But Stack Overflow is not the only programming site in the net. You can always ask somewhere else.

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180715/191410

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20850935/javascript-guidance-re-arranging-functions-into-files) the question you reference too?

Comment: [Where can I ask questions that don't fit or are off-topic for Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8401)

Comment: @rene yes you found the right question

Comment: @Krampus I read the material you reference.  I understand that SO has to limit what is being asked.  I do not believe I am using SO as a mentor; I answer hundreds of questions for myself.  I didn't see a site in the links that look right; but I'll hunt around.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fair warning - i have some suggestions, as I'm not sure your question is unsalvageable, but I'm not sure - I'm not a real dev.  :)

If I knew more, I'd try to edit it for you, but I think *at least part* of the problem is that rather than focusing on a specific problem, like:

> How can I prevent errors in one function from corrupting the functionality of others (including ones that were supposed to be validating the first one)?

You're focusing on what sounds like a super open-ended discussion about possible solutions, unfairly paraphrased as:

> I had this one idea, but I'm not sure if it's good, and I'm open to tons of others!

It's good to include the thoughts/efforst you've put in, but you don't want to make them solicitations for thoughts, counter-ideas, etc.  Instead, you can simply make them a modifier to your (ideally clearer) question - a way to show what you've considered so far:

> In trying to solve this myself, it seems to me like the best approach likely involves breaking up the js in some way to insulate shared functions from others' failure, but I can't figure out how to implement it.

At the end of the day, I'm not sure that would bring your question into scope, but it might.

Comment: I think the question is salvageable, but likely after the OP puts in more real research.

Comment: @Jaydies Thanks for your thoughts -- you are right, I asked if a solution would work instead of stating the problem.

Comment: @djechlin good point -- I'll see what I can find

Comment: @BettyMock that's not quite it. Asking if a solution would work is pretty okay; asking the pros and cons of a solution is not. But you have to make sure to define what "works" mean, which I guess is where problem statement comes in.